# How to get window title from name of executable file?

Tags: c#, process, window, exe, filenames

I write my app in C# and I have one problem. I have some executable file for example "spotify.exe". This app is running and i have to get title of window.

I am new in C# and I can't do this.
Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [MainWindowTitle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowtitle) property of the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/System.Diagnostics.Process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class :

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (Process process in processes)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Window title of {0} : {1}", process.ProcessName, process.MainWindowTitle);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Note that processes without a Form (e.g. console applications, background processes) will return an empty string for their `MainWindowTitle` .

Answer (score 2):

1. Get the process - `Process [] localByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");`
2. Get the title - `string Title = process.MainWindowTitle`

Answer (score 0):

As an example, to get the Spotify window title;

```
var procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("Spotify");

            foreach (var p in procs)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.MainWindowTitle))
                {
                    Label1.Text = p.MainWindowTitle;                    
                }
            }
```